# Sass function to add prefix before css class

Tags: sass, prefix, libsass

I'm trying to make a sass function that prefixes my class name, for example:

```
pf(.test) {
  display: block;
}
```

desired output:

```
.prefix-test {
  display: block;
}
```

What I've tried:

```
@function pf($class) {
    @return .#{$brand-prefix}-$class;
}
```

But I get an error

> > error reading values after @return
> >        Line 14  Column 9.

Any suggestions?